# mapping predictions using map2 and a model

Tags: r, purrr

I have two objects: An `xgb.model` (trained xgb model) and a test data set `dtest`.

The data looks like:

`xgb.model`

[image]

`dtest`

[image]

I am trying to make predictions on the lists. I can run the following to make a single prediction on the first list:

```
xgb.pred <- map2(.x = xgb.model[[1]], .y = dtest[[1]], .f = ~predict(.x, newdata = .y, type = 'prob'))
```

That is it makes the prediction on `Pza de Espana` using the `xgb.model` model and the `dtest` data.

However when I try to map over all lists I run into an error, applying:

```
xgb.pred <- map2(.x = xgb.model, .y = dtest, .f = ~ predict(.x, newdata = .y, type = 'prob'))
```

Gives me:

> Error in meanf(object, h = h, level = level, fan = fan, lambda =
>   lambda,  :    unused arguments (newdata = .y, type = "prob")

I know that the problem arises when I am trying to map over each of the lists. That is I cannot map over `dtest` and then again map over `pza de Espana` levels `[[1]]`, `[[2]]` and `[[3]]`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `flatten` the lists first, or use two nested `map2` calls.

Comment: I am not 100% sure how I can implement the two nested map2 calls… I went with `Prediction_Function <- function(i){
  xgb.pred <- map2(.x = xgb.model[[i]], .y = dtest[[i]], .f = ~predict(.x, newdata = .y, type = 'prob'))
}` and an `lapply` function in the end. It would still be interesting to see how it would work using `map2`.